# Override rows number affected returned by stored procedure that uses cursor inside

Tags: .net, ado.net, sql-server-2012, rowcount, nocount

I have a stored procedure simplified to the following code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @temp TABLE
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT @count = count(*) FROM @temp

DECLARE [cursor] FOR SELECT id FROM @temp
OPEN [cursor] FETCH NEXT FROM [cursor] INTO @id WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    exec anoterStoredProc @id
FETCH NEXT FROM [cursor] INTO @id
END
CLOSE [cursor]
DEALLOCATE [cursor]

SET NOCOUNT OFF

RETURN @count
```

But `ExecuteNonQuery()` still returns -1!

I can use `select @count` and `ExecuteScalar()` but want understand why my code doesn't work.

Seems that `NOCOUNT OFF` doesn't reset the server behavior, and `NOCOUNT ON` is still in-place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't mess with SET  ROWCOUNT - that does something very dangerous (if used incorrectly).

Return values are actually handled by adding a parameter with "direction" of ReturnValue. Alternatively, SELECT the value, and use ExecuteScalar.

Comment: So either ExecuteScalar(), or Direction=Return and reader it's value, not what has been returned by ExecuteNonQuery(), right

Comment: @abatishchev nothing is *returned* from `ExecuteNonQuery` - however, any out/ref/return-value parameters will be updated in-situ, so after the call you can obtain the `.Value` from that parameter

Answer (score 1):

`SET ROWCOUNT xx` is used to limit the number of rows returned by all subsequent queries. It would not be used to return a scalar value.

`RETURN xx` is used to return an integer value to the process calling the procedure. Generally this is used to indicate success (zero) or failure (not zero, presumably the error number). For specific values, you might find output parameters more convenient.

[added] `SET NOCOUNT` is an oblique command. When off, information is returned for every query run (select, update, insert, delete); when on, it is not. (Thus, setting it off where you do would have no effect.) The thing is, this inforation isn't a return value, parameter value, or dataset, but something else again (and is it a number? a string? I'm not sure). From everything I've ever heare it's a pain to work with, which is why I always start my stored procedures with `SET NOCOUNT on`.

In both cases, I don't seen where @count is being defined or assigned a value.

Comment: Will `return x` affect a value returned by `ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with ado.net to answer that. I'd go with @Marc Gravell's suggestiong (+1) of using a parameter with "ReturnValue". And I'm updating my answer to mention SET NOCOUNT.